# Is the new Gmail look built in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gmail

I was having a discussion with a colleague on this topic.  He thought that the new Gmail look was built with GWT.  I can't seem to find a definitive answer.  Anyone know for sure?

Comment: it is stated that gmail uses [closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/)

Comment: As of 2018 April, Gmail got new interface even though there is inbox.google.com. https://www.howtogeek.com/fyi/the-new-gmail-interface-launches-today/ There are minified javascript in the source but it's difficult to tell if it's generated by GWT or other tools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click on browser to view page source (when page is displaying your gmail inbox) says "no".

This page
http://code.google.com/closure/library/

says Google Closure Javascript is the basis of many Google products, including gmail.

Comment: It says "*base JavaScript library*" - **not** the *basis of many Google products*. As GWT can incorporate/run JS, I think that a better source is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Gmail is not written in GWT or Java.

However, the new Google Groups interface is:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview

You can find a reference from a Google GWT developer on what is using GWT here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/Mjjk5y9RQbw/hCWzIrZ1vzcJ

Other notable users are Chrome's web store

Comment: My understanding is that GMail is *definitely* written in Java (along with C++) - http://www.quora.com/What-programming-languages-is-Gmail-implemented-in -

Comment: You asked about the client side of things.  It's JavaScript with the closure library.

Answer (score 0):

gmail is not written in gwt but google inbox which might replace gmail uses gwt.